# Nginx Rewrite downloads file

Tags: php, nginx, centos6

So i have a statistics page for my own website and i wish to do the following;

```
User types: sub.mydomain/u/Username
End result: sub.mydomain/stats.php?player=Username

I want the end result to still show sub.domain/u/Username
```

However it seems that the php file gets downloaded, and this is a major issue as this contains my database information. I am using Centos 6 with Php fully installed along with php-fpm.

Here is my **virtual.conf** file:

```
   location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name stats.mydomain;

    root    /var/www/mydomain/public_html/stats/;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://mydomain/stats/home.php;
    }
    location /u {
    rewrite ^/u/(.*)$ /stats.php?player=$1 last;
    }
}
```

I have read other peoples questions and the responses however this does not seem to have resolved my issue.

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `location ~ php ...` block is in a separate server block. This needs to be inside the `server` curly brackets to take effect on your stats.mydomain.

Comment: Omg! Thank you very much!